# How to make PANIC BUTTON working on bluetooth

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, sos

I want to make a button on any tiny Bluetooth programming board so that I can connect it to android device via Bluetooth. When I'll press button on Bluetooth device it should communicate with android device and make a call or sms to preset contacts.

I don't wanna use any wifi boards such as ESP-01 and any other services like IFTTT. I want it to work via Bluetooth only to reduce size and power consumption. I searched but I didn't find any solution. Your help is appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like https://www.puck-js.com/ would do what you want....